# Convergent Sequences and Open Sets

Tags: real-analysis, metric-spaces

I have a question about convergent sequences in metric spaces:

Let $(M,d)$ be a metric space. Show that $A\subseteq M$ is open if and only if there is no sequence $\{x_n\}_1^\infty$ in $M-A$ that converges to some point $p\in A$.

I was able to prove the first direction of this, but I am stuck when trying to prove the second direction - if there is no sequence $\{x_n\}_1^\infty$ in $M-A$ that converges to some point $p\in A$, then $A\subseteq M$ is open. I have tried proving this by contradiction and considering if $A$ were NOT open, but I can't get much further than this. Any hints? Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

If $A$ is not open, then there is some point $a \in A$ such that every open
set containing $A$ contains an element of $A^c$.

The let $x_n \in B(a,{1 \over n}) \cap A^c$, we see that $x_n \to a$ 
and $x_n \in A^c$ for all $n$.

Answer (score 2):

If every convergent sequence in $M-A$ converges to a point in $M-A$ then $M-A$ is closed and therefore $A$ is open.